# Calculate cumulative standard deviation

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation of values in a time series, but I'd like to do it incrementally by advancing one day from the initial date value each time. I know there is a way to do this in R (probably using ddply?) that doesn't involve a nasty for-loop. Thanks for any help!

```
d<-seq(from=as.Date("2013-01-01"), to=as.Date("2013-02-01"), by="day")
v <-rnorm(32, 10, 5)
test.df<-data.frame(the_date=d, value=v)
```

Here's the way I'm doing it now.

```
result <- c()
for(i in 2:nrow(test.df)){ result[i-1] <- sd(test.df[1:i,]$value)}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TTR::runSD` with `cumulative=TRUE`.

```
library(TTR)
x <- xts(test.df[,2],test.df[,1])
runSD(x, n=1, cumulative=TRUE)
```

Comment: As much as we love `xts` objects, you don't actually need to convert to one here: `runSD(test.df[, 2], n=1, cumulative=TRUE)`

Comment: @GSee: Everyone who uses time-series needs xts.